# converting whole number to decimal to decimal

Tags: java

I want to write a code ie, If the input is a whole number, then number should be formatted with 2 decimal places(ie, If I give 10,It returns 10.00).otherwise If I give 10.123.It returns the same. How to verify whether a string is decimal or not and how to convert whole number to decimal?Could any one help?

Comment: Look into `DecimalFormat`, it almost certainly does what you want.

Comment: Do you want to calculate with the rounded decimal numbers or is this simply for display purposes?

Comment: In other words, you want all your numbers to appear textually as having at least two decimal places?

Comment: yes @BasilBourque

Comment: It is for display purposes@dpr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) can take a `String` in its constructor. Then all you need to do is determine a format, as [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) mentions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67262836/converting-whole-number-to-decimal-to-decimal#comment118891595_67262836), using [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```java
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);

System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal("9")));
System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal("9.1")));
System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal("9.00")));
System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal("9.123")));
System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal("9.123456")));
```

prints:

```java
9.00
9.10
9.00
9.123
9.123456
```

Answer (score 0):

If its for display purposes only simply go with the `DecimalFormat` as @JoachimSauer sugested:

```
final String number = "1.4";
try {
  Double numberObj = Double.valueOf(number);
  DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
  System.out.println(format.format(numberObj));
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  System.err.println("invalid number: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

To check if your `String` is a number you can create a `Double` instance from your string and catch `NumberFormatExcpetion` as shown above. This is performance wise not the best thing to do but I guess this is not your primary concern...